# In python3's hashlib, I keep getting a different digest when I run a text file through SHA256

Tags: python, python-3.x, sha256, hashlib

Here's my code:

```
# Instantiate hash function
filehash = hashlib.sha256()

# Calculate specified hash values
with fileinput.FileInput(files=(intake), mode='rb') as fintake:
    filehash.update(repr(fintake).encode("utf-8"))

return filehash.hexdigest()
```

This seems like it should return the same value each time. I am using this to calculate the hash for a text file that contains the word "Hello".

Every time I run the code, it returns a different digest. E.g.

92220b5bd4b5370126ddce16c21bb91cc9c9c2e0a013c8a38bbdafbdb2322cbb

0bcb26341a564c07a98060f90df9df3ebad5129ef5c2d6afa26ba5a9d6d90302

58b3bee46210a1af0f9d454c56172e2b14664644acf59a0a54025c4e61c8e794

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the string you're hashing... and then spend some time reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input).

Comment: You aren't hashing the file contents but rather the repr of the FileInput object. As the repr has the object ID in it which explains why it changes.

Comment: That was super helpful, thanks. (sincerely)